# Should I separate grounds with optocoupler and dc converter?

Tags: ground, opto-isolator, emc

I have a 24V input to a DC/DC converter, output is 3.3V. 
the 24V is also passed to an opto-coupler (diode side) while the secondary side (NPN) has a 3.3V-made from the 24V. So the opto-coupler is used as a level shifter.

I thought about separating the grounds for the opto-coupler. The input 24V will have a gnd1, while the 3.3V will have a gnd2 to raise the noise immunity. But, the 3.3V is transformed from the same 24V passed to the input of the opto-coupler (which has a different ground).
In this situation, will this give good results in terms of EMI, SI, point of view?
Thanks all!

Comment: This question stinks as it stands very vague, needs a schematic or a pic of the PCB

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to say without knowing your application and requirements what you *should* do.

If the DC-DC converter is not isolated, then the grounds of the 24 V and 3.3 V logic are connected.  In that case, there is probably no advantage to splitting them at the opto-coupler, and also probably no reason to use an opto-coupler at all.

On the other hand, if the DC-DC converter is isolated and that isolation is needed, then you would use opto-couplers (or other isolation devices) for all signals that cross the boundary.

Comment: +1 for the opto-coupler probably not being needed. Isolation is a poorly understood subject and the number of unnecessary opto-couplers we see is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

> In this situation, will this give good results in terms of EMI, SI,
>   point of view?

Separating grounds doesn't always do that, I can't go into great detail without seeing the application. If you split the ground planes you can start making antennas especially around a DC to DC converter. If you need isolation and you have a transformer, I could see reason for spliting the ground plane, if there isn't a good reason then in most cases your better off with a solid one.

High frequency currents (any current for that matter) takes the path of lowest impedance, splitting the ground plane usually increases impedance for currents to return to the source.

Comment: Can you elaborate? It seems that I've got to a point where I have to share grouds between "isolated" circuits. My receiving circuit seems to be very sensitive that even when optocoupler is not connected to anything, I can fire it with just touching cathode with my finger (or simply touching any metal part of the receiver circuit). Connecting optocoupler to the main circuit resulting in an unpredictable bechaviour of the receiver 
 - unless I share grounds between them...

Answer (score 0):

It is better to keep them seperated, to avoid unpredictable ground currents. If for example an Arduino of 3.3V is used at the 3.3V end, then connect the output GND of the optocoupler to the GND of the Arduino. Then the output signal of the optocoupler is relative to the Arduino GND, and that is how it should be.

Wires with ground currents can cause voltage drops, and noise. When the ground current can choose between two wires, it is hard to predict which one will be used. It might not be the thickest wire, but the wire with the best magnetic coupling to the positive current going in the other direction. For high frequency currents, it is even more complex.

Comment: But technically, if the noise is on the 24V, then it will be also on the 3.3V (after the DC/DC converter). Wouldn't it? So, in if this is the case, than what's the point of separating grounds, when the voltage carry the same noise (from same origin)?

Comment: Every wire and every conversion can increase the noise. There is no such thing as the same noise. Especially with ground currents, every piece of wire and every device connected somewhere in the ground wires can change things.

The noise of the 24V is probably not on the 3.3V. It can be gone completely. For example a voltage circuit for a microfoon has a very silent voltage output. A DC/DC converter introduces noise because it is a switching/oscillating regulator.